# PromQL: counter and rate hint

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

When I'm trying to build a panel into my grafana dashboard using a `counter` metric, it's telling me:

> Selected metric is a counter. Consider calculating rate of counter by adding rate().

1. Why it suggest me above hint?
2. Has any relation with `scrape_interval`?

I'm using those metrics:

- `method_timed_seconds_count` -> counter
- `method_timed_seconds_max` -> gauge
- `method_timed_seconds_sum` -> counter

How should I visualize them? I mean, which promQL should I use?

Currently, I'm using them straightforwardly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Counter metrics](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter) are rarely useful when displayed on the graph. For example, try obtaining any useful information from the graph on the `method_timed_seconds_sum` metric. That's why it is recommended wrapping these metrics into [rate](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rate) or [increase](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) functions:

- `rate(m[d])` returns the **average** per-second increase rate for counters matching `m` [series selector](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors) over the lookbehind window `d`. For example, `rate(method_timed_seconds_count[5m])` returns the average requests per second over the last 5 minites.
- `increase(m[d])` returns the increase of counters matching `m` over the lookbehind window `d`. For example, `increase(method_timed_seconds_count[1h])` returns the number of requests during the last hour.

Both `method_timed_seconds_count` and `method_timed_seconds_sum` counters can be used for calculating the average request duration on an arbitrary lookbehind window. For example, the following query returns the average request duration over the last 5 minutes:

```
increase(method_timed_seconds_sum[5m])
  /
increase(method_timed_seconds_count[5m])
```

E.g. this query divides the sum of duration of all the requests during the last 5 minutes by the the number of requests during the last 5 minutes.